# LIKE %term% vs. LIKE %term

Tags: mysql, sql

Is there any performance benefit between the following two queries:

```
SELECT path FROM path WHERE name LIKE '%filename'
```

Or -

```
SELECT path FROM path WHERE name LIKE '%filename%'
```

What would be the difference in MySQL execution? And other than syntactic correctness, would there be any advantage to using `%term` over `%term%` ?

Comment: Don't they mean two different things? Doesn't `%filename` match strings ending in "filename" while `%filename%` match any string with "filename" in it?

Comment: Surprised at the close votes "Unclear". This question is very clear.

Comment: Why not just type `EXPLAIN SELECT path FROM path WHERE name LIKE '%filename%'` into the mysql client and see what the difference in execution plan is?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`%filename` will match any record that has `filename` at the END of the field.

`%filename%` will match any record that has `filename` anywhere INSIDE the field.

e.g.

```
                  %filename      filename%     %filename%
filenamefoobar        N              Y              Y
foofilenamebar        N              N              Y
foobarfilename        Y              N              Y
argielbargle          N              N              N
```

Some DBMS systems might be smart enough to turn `%filename` into a match at just the end of the string. But generally speaking, any `LIKE` query that has a leading `%` wildcard prevents the use of indexes.

Comment: Really, there's no duplicate of this?

Answer (score 2):

Performance difference? why not just run both the version of query and see for yourself.

In above queries you are checking two different things.

with `LIKE '%filename'` you are checking values for `name` column ends with  `filename` string.

with `name LIKE '%filename%'` you are checking values for `name` column have `filename` string in between.

Answer (score 0):

In both cases the RDBMS cannot use a regular index because the beginning of the string is unknown. Unless you specify something like a "reverse" index, which is possible on some RDBMSs (and which *could* make '%filename' faster), there should not be any preformance difference.

Strictly speaking with '%filename' the RDBMS has to read the next character to make sure that it is the end of the string, which is not required in the case of '%filename%', but that cost is neglectable.

Ans of course '%filename' and '%filename%' mean two different things as already pointed out by Rahul, Marc B and Colonel Thirty Two